# Sound Blaster Recon3D not working

Tags: sound, sound-blaster

I installed ubuntu 12.10 on my computer and I'm totally new to ubuntu.
I cannot get my sound card to work, it's a sound blaster recon3D. I read that this card now has support on this ubuntu version(HDA creative).
Here what happens:
Sometimes when I turn on the computer, it does not make any sound at all, but ubuntu detects it, I can configure the sound settings.
Sometimes when I turn on my pc, every time a sound is played, I can hear only white noise(a realy loud noise) coming from my speakers and headphnoes.
I tried to find something on the internet but I only found a solution that works for HDA Intel cards.
As a work arround I'm using my HDMI audio that comes from my Nvidia video card (GTX570).
Thanks every one!

Comment: Heyyo, I just want to also add for anyone else trying to use a Soundblaster Recon 3D in any form of Linux? Use 32bit... works flawlessly without any tinkering. 64bit is hit-or-miss and sometimes that rc.local fix wasn't working for me. I can say that in 32bit, Ubuntu, Xubuntu and Kubuntu all work perfect... 64bit it didn't work with or without the fix some of the time. I've tried with many different kernel versions too. I run a Soundblaster Recon 3D Fatal1ty Professional Edition... seriously Creative... ran out of fancy words or would you have added more? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Workaround

Open a terminal and run the following command:

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

### Explanation

This will add a new line with `options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` so that ALSA initializes with the proper options set instead of initializing ALSA with incompatible options, removing the module afterwards and reloading it with compatible options as described in the original answer.

Corresponding bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1166529

---

**Original Answer**

Ha! Found a solution myself. Here it goes:

Add these two lines before the command "exit 0" on the file rc.local on /etc directory:

```
rmmod snd_hda_intel
modprobe snd_hda_intel position_fix=1
```

This should  fix.

Comment: I think [this is a better link, the upstream report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=55541).