# Consistent Sound Issues in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I'm a new user of Ubuntu, and a relatively new user of Linux in general. I recently switched from Ubuntu MATE to the latest version of Ubuntu released on Ubuntu's official page, due to less support for MATE than Ubuntu, and for the reason that I was having sound issues in MATE.

At first, it was just my headphone jack that wouldn't work. I searched the web for solutions, and eventually got them working. Unfortunately I don't remember how I accomplished this, I just remember that I did. All sound worked fine for the next couple days, but then the headphone jacks just suddenly didn't work again. Once again, I searched the internet for solutions. After attempting something I found (I believe it was altering the alsa-base.conf file), the sound just died altogether. Since then, nothing has worked.

**Things I've tried:**

Alsa reload and alsa force-reload (Many times)

Unmuting everything in alsamixer

The solution found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284183/sound-blaster-recon3d-not-working)

Changing volume settings in Sound

I'm on an Alienware 15R2, with a Sound Blaster 3Di sound card. For some reason in alsamixer it shows my card as an "HDA Intel PCH". I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but this is something I suspect could be the issue.

**Output of lspci -v | grep -i audio:**

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)

Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point -H HD Audio

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: For some reason, the sound suddenly started working again after a couple days. I've been using Windows since the issue began, but decided to boot into Ubuntu just to see if anything had changed. Both speakers and headset works. Don't know why or how it works now, but I would be surprised if it didn't die again in the near future.